# Can't return a int if the XML-file is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

Trying to set a unique ID to things that saves in a XML-file.
As now this is my code:

```
public int getUniqueID()
    {
        var idlist = from ids in connectToXML().Descendants("moviereview")
                      select (int)ids.Element("id");

        int biggestId = idlist.Max();

        if (biggestId< 1 || biggestId.Equals(null))
        {
            return biggestId;
        }
        else
        {
            return biggestId + 1;
        }        
    }
```

I am trying to get a value to return if the ID is null or 0 when it runs for the first time. Because I can get it to work if I manually add something to the XML-document and then start with the ID 1 f.ex. But if the XML-file is empty it won't return a value. Am I overlooking anything?

Comment: And by *it won't return a value* you mean there is an exception thrown? What exception?

Comment: It wont return anything at all. It return a value only if there is a node called 'ID' in the XML file that return 1 etc. But when the XML-file is empty and I want to created a node called ID for a first time it won't let me, because the the method 'getUniqueID' don't return a value

Comment: It will always return _something_ or throw an exception, because the return type is not void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
public int getUniqueID()
{
    var idlist = from ids in connectToXML().Descendants("moviereview")
                  select (int)ids.Element("id");

    int biggestId = idlist.DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
    return biggestId + 1;     
}
```

Comment: +1. You may want to add presence/emptines check for `id` element `where !ids.Element("id") && !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(ids.Element("id").Value))`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In most cases that's not necessary, because when there is a parent element (`"moviereview"` in this case) it has exact same structure, so you can assume there is an `id` with `int` value.